# To add External Spring jars for a spring project without Maven

Tags: java, spring

I just downloaded the Spring IDE and Tool suite from Eclipse Market place.I am creating a sample Spring project using Spring core containers. I am following a tutorial video for that.  I want to set build path by adding external downloaded Spring jars for that I have gone to build path of a specific project and I don't know where my downloaded external spring jars.  I have searched in my local drive in java folder in programming files and also where my eclipse is saved.  But I cannot find where my external spring jar files saved.

Kindly tell me the path where I can find external downloaded jars from eclipse Marketplace

Comment: But why do you want to do that? I recommend using Gradle or Maven. You can check this link to see how to setup using Gradle [spring-boot-setup-gradle](https://fastfoodcoding.com/tutorials/1503156546006/crud-operations-using-spring-boot-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Suite tool is Rapid Application Development plugin, which helps to decrease spring configuration time and help you focus on core logic of your application.

Even though, As [Martin Lippert](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/109061-is-it-required-to-add-spring-jar-files-at-java-build-path-for-every-new-project) Explain below, you might have to use [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) (Build Automation tool, And project dependency manager) for creating spring project.

> people often use Maven for their dependency management (or Ivy or something else) and would like to use a specific version of the Spring framework (instead of the libs that are inside STS and used by STS itself). But you can define a user-defined Library that contains all the necessary Spring framework JARs and maybe others and just add that user-defined library to each project. Would make it a bit easier as adding several JARs all over again.

Maven uses a filesystem tree as a repository to store jar files with there metadata(dependency, version, etc.) which is located (by default) under your `home` or `My Document` Path within `.m2` directory (folder).